# React, Best method for rendering a message on a component event

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

New to react to not quite sure what is the best method here.

What I want to do is render a component (a error message component) when I run an event on another component.

The problem here is I should be able to render multiple notifications as well, each of them with a different state. (error, warning, success).

Additional information,

My main application class,

```
MainLayout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {this.props.header}

        {this.props.notification}

        {this.props.content}

        {this.props.footer}

      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

this is my notification Class, which gets rendered at `{this.props.notification}`

```
SwiftNotification = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      type: 'not-error',
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <div className={ this.state.type + " jwlnotification container-fluid text-center"}>
          text for this....
        </div>
    )
  }
});
```

So on inviteMembers function I want to be able to render the notification component but outside this component.

```
BandEvent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    location: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },

  inviteMembers(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Meteor.call('inviteMembers', this.props.id, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.reason);
      } else {
        // what do we want to do here if we are successful..
        console.log(data);

      }
    });

  },

  render() {

    let { id, name, location } = this.props;

    return (
      <li className="bandEvent" ><button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={this.inviteMembers}> Invite Members </button> {name} at {location}</li>
    )
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flux-like implementation such as redux to store notification information in a single object. Any component could then dispatch a notification with the meta-data you require (`message`, `message_type`). Your notification component would then consume the notifications and contain all of the business logic you'd need around notifications: How many to display at once, how to display them, when to dismiss them, etc.

Edit: It seems like this is a package you could use, or at least the source is an example of the logic I was describing. https://github.com/indexiatech/re-notif

Comment: Sorry I think I've explained myself incorrectly, I want to be able to display a message (a custom message) to let the user know if some action was successful or not. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant how organize message component and run its method from outside.

Take a look to Confirm.openModal method, any React component can call it regardless of relationship between Confirm component and call component. Also it works without declaration in global WINDOW.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r7jop83wk4

Comment: how safe is it, isn't that anti pattern?